# Uncaught error when applying archive template to post categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have created an archive template using elementor plugin and have applied it to my categories but I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   generate_do_element_classes() in
>   /nas/content/live/ablefuture/wp-content/themes/astra-child/archive.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /nas/content/live/ablefuture/wp-includes/template-loader.php(78):
>   include() #1 /nas/content/live/ablefuture/wp-blog-header.php(19):
>   require_once(‘/nas/content/li…’) #2
>   /nas/content/live/ablefuture/index.php(17):
>   require(‘/nas/content/li…’) #3 {main} thrown in
>   /nas/content/live/ablefuture/wp-content/themes/astra-child/archive.php
>   on line 14

The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

https://ablefuture.wpengine.com/blog/category/home-improvement

Can anyone pls assist?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
generate_do_element_classes()
```

is a new function in GP 2.2.

If your child theme is using it, you need to make sure your parent theme is running at least 2.2.

Let me know if works or not